# Use c# to animate instead of Animator in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, state

Well I know animator system in Unity is very useful for many things but I find myself having my own state machine in the code and somehow the state machine that the animator provides is not accurate due to blend time maybe I dont know, so I find often my character being in state 2 in the animator state machine and state 0 in my own state machine and its crazy as I cant seem to make it match in limit cases when its about to end the action. So I would like to know if there is a way to just say with code "play this animation from frame A to frame B" and loop it or not loop, that would be much better for me, of course I will lose all the blend features but really I will be better, all I can fin in the docs refer to using the animator so far. Thanks a lot for any help regarding this =)

Edit: Forgot to add that I found Animation.Play but apparently this only play animation saved on separate files like when we use the Animation timeline to record a certain motion, but I have a character with a lot of frames there and I dont think it serves in this case (or in my tests it never finds the specified animation at least, maybe i miss somethnig)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before anything, you can your own state machine with Animator. in fact, you don't need to two different state machine for your purposes. (Watch this video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AD4JIXQDw0s)) 
and about your question, I found a good answer here: [Link](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1013423/animation-state-get-current-frame.html)

> From what I've seen you can either do AnimationState.normalizedTime
>   which returns the progress of an animation on a scale of 0 to 1. So if
>   you have a 30 frame animation and you want frame 15, you can do if
>   (normalizedTime == 0.5)* Or the better and more reliable option is to
>   use AnimationEvents that fire on specific frames.
>
> *You won't really be able to do this if we're dealing in floats--You can only get the approximate value or you'll have to check greater
>   then or equal to 0.4 AND less then or equal to 0.6 because the
>   animation could go faster than the current frame rate or the
>   normalized time value could be 0.50000001 because of the nature of
>   float values.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks a million for this =), dont know why all tutorials and sites I watched about the animator were always telling to insert the code in the player creating something like a parallel state machine when as you said we can use the animator state machine for our own purposes inserting the code in the states with enter and exit functions and even being able to know the frame the animation is at, well I think that as said perhaps a event is more reliable as its unskippable, right? so even if animation skips frame the event will be triggered, correct me if Im wrong

Comment: hey asdronin, your welcome ^_^
i think you are right.  it's not important that you use Animator or your own state machine. both of them is based on Unity Animation System and it's said that Animation Event should be fired in situation (https://forum.unity.com/threads/animation-events-not-always-firing-mecanim.428786/)

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot again, I think I will use time to see where in the animation is it, perhaps events are fixed now but I think I feel safer to say if its over time 0.5 or whatever then do something, will take a bit more time maybe but certainly more precise, I like accuracy in the stuff I make even if its low quality in the end my games are accurate =). Thank you very much Mohammad, you have discovered me a whle new world with this info =). Best of luck in your projects and everything =)

Comment: Good luck bro, Feel free to contact me whenever you want :)